# Nuxt command unknown after creating project and runnin npm install

Tags: nuxt3

I am not very used to Nuxt.js, and I try to reproduce this tutorial
[Laravel -Nux3 authentication guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NY9yoqoN72w).

After having created the Nuxt.js project with

```
npx nuxi init <project-name>
cd <project-name>
npm install
```

When I try to use the command

```
nuxt add layout default
```

I get an error

> bash: nuxt: commande inconnue... in english bash: nuxt: unknow command

What is the problem here? How can I get this Nuxt.js command?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message "bash: nuxt: unknown command" indicates that the nuxt command is not recognized in your command-line environment. This error commonly occurs when the Nuxt.js package is not installed globally or if the installation was not successful.

To resolve this issue and make the nuxt command available, you can try the following steps:
1.Ensure that you have Node.js and npm installed on your system. You can check their versions by running the following commands:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

If node.js or npm is not installed you will need to install before proceeding

Verify if the nuxt package is installed globally. You can check by running the following command:

```
npm list -g nuxt
```

If package is not listed, you need to install globally by:

```
npm install -g nuxt
```

3. After installing Nuxt.js globally, you should be able to use the nuxt command in your terminal. Try running nuxt to verify if it is recognized:

   nuxt
   If it displays the Nuxt.js version and available commands, it means the installation was successful.
4. Finally, you can proceed with running the nuxt add command:

   npx nuxt add layout default

The `npx` command is used here to ensure that the `nuxt` command is executed from the locally installed Nuxt.js package within your project.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I apologize for answering so late but I have been busy with many other things. Your answer helped me a lot. I had just to prepend the command with sudo. It works now.

Comment: I am happy it helped

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Answer (score 0):

You need to install global nuxt with cmd:

```
npm install -g nuxt
```